# Match some columns exactly, and some partially with inner_join

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

I have two dataframes from different sources that refer to the same people, but due to errors from self-reported data, the dates may be slightly off.

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name= c("Ann", "Betsy", "Charlie", "Dave"), 
                  dob= c(as.Date("2000-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2001-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                         as.Date("2002-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2003-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(name= c("Ann", "Charlie", "Elmer", "Fred"), 
                  dob= c(as.Date("2000-01-11", "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2004-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                         as.Date("2001-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2006-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to match by exact name, with dplyr like:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("name"))

name    dob.x   dob.y
Ann     2000-01-01  2000-01-11
Charlie     2002-01-01  2004-01-01
```

but also by dates of birth (dob) within 30 days, with the fuzzyjoin package like:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

difference_inner_join(df1, df2, by=c("dob"), max_dist = 30)

name.x  dob.x   name.y  dob.y
Ann     2000-01-01  Ann     2000-01-11
Betsy   2001-01-01  Elmer   2001-01-01
```

But combine both criteria, so that only Ann would be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do this:

```
 difference_inner_join(df1, df2, by=c("dob"), max_dist = 30) %>%
  filter(name.x == name.y)

  name.x      dob.x name.y      dob.y
1    Ann 2000-01-01    Ann 2000-01-11
```

Comment: Perfect! I had implemented this earlier with loops and it took > 5 minutes on my real data with >100,000 rows. Your solution works in <15 seconds.

Comment: I was hoping to find a function call to put it all into `fuzzy_inner_join`s `match_fun=list(...)` but it just seems to take `=`, `>=`, `<=` aso.. But glad it helped.

Comment: I think your solution is more readable than stuffing it all in the inner_join function

Answer (score 3):

Relying on dplyr and base R alone.
I rarely need fuzzy joins. `inner_join` and subsequently `filter` usually is enough

```
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("name")) %>% 
  filter(abs(difftime(dob.x,dob.y, units = "days"))<30)
```

result

```
  name      dob.x      dob.y
 1  Ann 2000-01-01 2000-01-11
```