# inner_join() with range of values for one of the keys (year)

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join, tidyverse, fuzzyjoin

I have two datasets that are formatted like this:

```
df1
#>           Artist          Album Year
#> 1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967
#> 2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971
```

and

```
df2
#>            Album Year      Producer
#> 1  Sgt. Pepper's 1966 George Martin
#> 2 Sticky Fingers 1971  Jimmy Miller
```

I'd like to do an `inner_join` by Album and Year, but sometimes the 'Year' field is off by one year: for example, Sgt. Peppers is listed as 1967 in df1 by 1966 in df2.

So if I run:

```
df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("Album", "Year"))
```

I get:

```
df3
#>           Artist          Album Year     Producer
#> 1 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971 Jimmy Miller
```

Whereas, I would like both albums to join, so long as something like `(df1$Year == df2$Year + 1)|(df1$Year == df2$Year - 1)`.

I cannot just simple join by 'Album' because in my real data set there are some identically titled 'Albums' that are distinguished by 'Year'.

Code for the datasets below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
      Artist = c("Beatles", "Rolling Stones"),
       Album = c("Sgt. Pepper's", "Sticky Fingers"),
        Year = c(1967, 1971)
)
df1

df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
       Album = c("Sgt. Pepper's", "Sticky Fingers"),
        Year = c(1966, 1971),
    Producer = c("George Martin", "Jimmy Miller")
)
df2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try using the `sqldf` package here, since your requirement can easily be phrased using a SQL join:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT t1.Artist, t1.Album, t1.Year, t2.Album, t2.Year, t2.Producer
        FROM df1 t1
        INNER JOIN df2 t2
            ON ABS(t1.Year - t2.Year) <= 1"
df3 <- sqldf(sql)
```

If you want to select all fields from both tables, then use:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM ...
```

But note that in general `SELECT *` is frowned upon, and it is desirable to always list out the columns to select.

Comment: If I want to `SELECT` all fields from both t1 and t2, is there a simple wildcard for the first line of code? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a [rolling join](https://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2016/06/understanding-datatable-rolling-joins.html) would take care of this. It works for your data sample, but it's possible there might be tricky edge cases in your actual data.

In the code below, `roll="nearest"` will match the nearest year value for each album (the "rolling" part applies only to the last join column, `Year` in this case).

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

setkey(df1, Album, Year)
setkey(df2, Album, Year)

joined = df1[df2, roll="nearest"]

joined
```

> ```
>            Artist          Album Year      Producer
> 1:        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1966 George Martin
> 2: Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971  Jimmy Miller
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Year + 1` to `df2` and then join? You can also add `Year - 1` if you want to cover range in both direction.

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2 %>%  bind_rows(df2 %>%  mutate(Year = Year + 1)),
                by = c("Album", "Year"))

#          Artist          Album Year      Producer
#1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967 George Martin
#2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971  Jimmy Miller
```

Comment: Can I check my understanding of your solution, please? Am I right in thinking that you're using `bind_rows` to essentially copy and add on a duplicate of df2 with all of the years increased, so then df2 is twice the size, and more likely to join?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's just a copy of df2 with years value increased by 1.

Comment: Is there a way I can cover the other direction in the same code? I tried `inner_join(df1, df2 %>%  bind_rows(df2 %>%  mutate(Year = Year + 1) %>% bind_rows(df2 %>%  mutate(Year = Year - 1)), by = c("Album", "Year")))` but I must be doing something wrong. Thank you

Comment: @RAndStata yes, do `inner_join(df1, 
           bind_rows(df2, df2 %>% mutate(Year = Year + 1), df2 %>% mutate(Year = Year - 1)), by = c("Album", "Year"))`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, this can also be solved using `data.table`'s *non-equi joins*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c(.SD, .(ym1 = Year - 1, yp1 = Year + 1))][
  setDT(df2), on = .(Album, ym1 <= Year, yp1 >= Year), nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>            Artist          Album Year  ym1  yp1      Producer
> 1:        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967 1966 1966 George Martin
> 2: Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971 1971 1971  Jimmy Miller
> ```

or

```
setDT(df1)[, c("ym1", "yp1") := .(Year - 1, Year + 1)][setDT(df2), 
           on = .(Album, ym1 <= Year, yp1 >= Year), nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>            Artist          Album Year  ym1  yp1      Producer
> 1:        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's 1967 1966 1966 George Martin
> 2: Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers 1971 1971 1971  Jimmy Miller
> ```

which modifies `df1`.

---

BTW: There is a feature request https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639 to allow for *on-the-fly columns in `on`*. If this is implemented, above expression would become

```
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), on = .(Album, Year - 1 <= Year, Year + 1 >= Year), nomatch = 0L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is reading this question in the future, the above answers are great. Another answer is to:

1. Join all of the matching Albums
2. Filter out only the records where the years are close:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863846/8742237

```
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("Album")) %>% 
  filter(abs(Year.x - Year.y)<2)

>           Artist          Album Year.x Year.y      Producer
> 1        Beatles  Sgt. Pepper's   1967   1966 George Martin
> 2 Rolling Stones Sticky Fingers   1971   1971  Jimmy Miller
```